# import issue with python

Tags: python, import, python-3.4

I had this issue earlier, but I've figured out more, so I figured I'd ask with more information.

I used `pip` to install the python API `spotify`, and now I'm having trouble getting it to work.

I have `file.py` in my `home` directory, and at the start of that I call

```
import spotipy
```

Then, that calls the `__init__.py` file, which then has the line

`from client import Spotify, SpotifyException`

This line fails, even though `client.py` is in the same folder as `__init__.py`.

The message is `ImportError: No module named 'client'`.

The only way I have been able to get this to work, is by also putting `file.py` in the same folder as `__init__.py` and `client.py`, but this seems ridiculous, and I'd rather not have to have all my files stored there. Does anyone know how to fix this? Is it a matter of the path or something?

Answer (score 0):

I'd check and see if there's a stray file named `client.py` or `client.pyc` in the directory you were originally running from.

Answer (score 0):

Install Spotify with easy_install rather than pip. It will be fixed.